# Weird error with addresses

Tags: truffle, ethers.js, addresses, bignumber

I'm stuck trying to make a truffle test pass with a code similar to next one:

```
  1  const addr1 = '0x35987A0F9AE77012a514835D6DC88b708bC646D6',
  2        addr2 = "0x4F1C4e17bAa273EdCcB5c49E07ee87D264cFEdfE" ;
  3  await contract.methodA(addr1); // <-- Works as expected.
  4  await contract.methodA(addr2); // <-- FAIL!!!!
```

The error obtained is:

```
result: value out of range (argument="value", value=20, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.6.1)
```

Is it there something weird with addr2 or can anyone confirm that this is actually due
to some problem in truffle internal?

Some extra details.

```
$ npm list
├── @truffle/hdwallet-provider@2.1.2
├── chai-bn@0.3.1
├── chai@4.3.7
├── mocha@10.1.0
└── truffle@5.6.7
```

The previous address is the result of next solidity code:

address(bytes20(bytes.concat(/*bytes10*/ val1, "", /*bytes10*/ val2)))

Some potential bugs that trigger this behavior:

- BN bug: https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/pull/295/files
- Lock versions for BigNumber fix:  https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/commit/a27ef825772f72071439c51e51180b6fcc64f03c
- Serious Bug: BN.js incorrectly computes hexsting: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/3017

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example? It is impossible to reproduce the error message with the code in the question.

Comment: Finally it was due to a series of related CI/CD errors. The testing contract was not compiling the correct (latest) version and throwing a require error in a public view method. Simultaneously this require method was causing a second "error" in the ethers client library that gets confused by assert/require errors in read-only methods. ( I'm not sure whether requires or asserts are really allowed in view/pure methods. They compile with no warnings but In practice, since client libraries do not support them properly maybe it's better to avoid them).

Comment: That's the way solidity works. If the function reverts with a message it is returned to the caller. The caller using the exit status can determine if it is a successful execution or a revert message.

Comment: Thanks. It looks to me that the ethers.js client is not checking that "exit status" and just trying to parse the response as a 20-bytes address. ethers.js is an indirect dependency in my truffle project. Previously it was using web3.js. With web3.js the require was converted to an JS exception { reason: "REQUIRE_ERROR_IN_SOLIDITY" }. and captured properly by my try-catch block. The same Solidity code and JSON-RPC invocation generates an wrong value-out-of-range.  (But I need to find time to investigate a bit more the cause)